# Why Locking is not necessary for Local/Stack variables in multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have worked on multithreading (in Qt) but i lack an in-depth knowledge. I think that the run-time never duplicates an execution code. A function will remain in precisely one memory location which all callers or object will use to invoke it. In multithreading i read that each thread gets its own stack, Instruction Pointers and so on. Let's say we have a global function which translates to assembly algorithm like this:

```
//GlobalFunction()
instruction 1 : move value 4 into accumulator
instruction 2 : add 5 to content of accumulator
instruction 3 : subtract 1 from content of accumulator
//some more stuff and function returns

//thread 1
call GlobalFunction()

//thread 2
call GlobalFunction()
```

now maybe the instruction pointer of thread 1 points to instruction 3 while thread 2 gets the slice and executes instruction 1. After this thread 1 executes instruction 3. Won't the accumulator data be corrupted for it? If so then why do functions using only non-static local variables do not require locking in multithreaded environment?

P.S: Also i suppose a single instruction is atomic not a group of instructions, so implementation might not get a chance of flushing the register data out into some storage location before executing instruction of another thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there is only one set of registers on a CPU (for simplicity, I'm assuming a single core system), the system manages the register file such that each thread has it's own separate register state - when the OS switches from one thread to another, the first thread's registers are saved and the second thread's saved registers are restored.

For automatic/stack variables each thread gets it's own stack, so unless the thread does something to explicitly share such a variable (by passing the address or a reference to another thread), those variables are not shared and so are thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

The OS and CPU handle the registers and assorted CPU state. A multiple-core CPU has multiple accumulators/registers- one for each active thread. A single-core CPU can't be interrupted in the middle of an instruction- the whole visible CPU state is in the registers, which are saved and restored by OS.

Answer (score 0):

No, each thread also has its own execution registers (including any accumulators that the processor might have).

On multi-processor systems each processor has its own registers (that's the core of what makes it a separate processor), and when multiple threads are switched onto the same processor the register state is saved & restored.